# iOS - Achieving animation like Cut the Rope or Angry Birds

Tags: ios, opengl-es

How are these types of games built with the animation they contain? I'm really intrigued but have no idea where to start with this?

Initially I thought of drawRect:, but I realise that must be quite slow to get the animations and shear number of elements on screen (esp on older devices)

Is it something to do with lower technologies? Like OpenGL? What about the new Metal technology announced?

Comment: Angry birds was built in Box 2d.

Comment: How about Cut the Rope? I’m interested in the way they animate objects, like the bubble popping etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to be looking at is [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html). It was introduced in iOS 6 as Apple's own API for creating rich 2D games. Before iOS 6, developing games required either a third-party library (most of which contractually take a portion of your profits, in addition to Apple's own cuts), or write your own game engine from scratch (likely a daunting task for people who have never developed any games before).

Unfortunately I don't know which libraries are used to make the popular games that you mentioned.

**EDIT:** UIImageView has simple frame-by-frame animation support built right in, and it's about as easy to use as you could possibly ask for. The following will show a 1-second-long 30x30 animation consisting of 5 frames that loop indefinitely:

```
UIImageView *animatedImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 30.f, 0.f];
animatedImage.animationImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyAnimatedImage1"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyAnimatedImage2"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyAnimatedImage3"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyAnimatedImage4"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyAnimatedImage5"]];
animatedImage.animationDuration = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview:animatedImage];
[animatedImage startAnimating];
```

If you wanted to set a limit on how many times it will loop, set `animatedImage.animationRepeatCount`.

Comment: I’m using SpriteKit at the moment, but struggling to figure out how to implement certain animations. Specifically, I have a bubble which I want to pop but I want to do it programatically and can’t figure out the best approach to go ahead. Any ideas how I might do this in SpriteKit?

Comment: That animation is almost certainly an image animation (not procedurally generated).

Comment: @AdamCarter That sounds like an animation that would have to be hand-drawn frame-by-frame, and animated using an image sequence.

Comment: I assumed as much, but my question was how do I do this programatically?

Comment: @AdamCarter Just updated answer. Hope this helps